Find the Coordinates of Point M in Right Triangle MBQ in Cartesian Coordinates
In a Cartesian coordinate system, there is a right triangle $MBQ$ with the right angle at the vertex $M$. The coordinates of the acute-angled vertices are given as $Q(0, -1)$ and $B(4, 0)$. The lengths of the sides are:
$$QB = \sqrt{17}  \text{  (hypotenuse)}$$
$$QM = \frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}}  \text{  (one leg)}\quad\space$$
$$BM = \frac{3\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}} \text{  (other leg)}\space$$
Given these conditions, how can I determine the coordinates of the vertex $M$? I need to solve for $M$ using the given distances and the properties of the right triangle.
$$\text{Let } M(m, n), \text{ then } [n - (-1)]^2 + m^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2$$,$$n^2 + (4 - m)^2 = \left(3 \frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2$$

So, what did you try yourself?

\text{Let } M(m, n), \text{ then } [n - (-1)]^2 + m^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2,n^2 + (4 - m)^2 = \left(3 \frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2

$$M=(0,-1)+{1\over10}(4,1)+{3\over10}(-1,4)$$

Your comment seems unreadable, something is wrong with formatting.


If you want to use the property of right angle triangle you need to find one more equation. You found:
$n^2+(4-m)^2=\frac{9\times 17=153}{10}=MB^2$
For another equation we have , the coordinates of mid point of BQ is:
$D(\frac{0+2}2=2, \frac{-1+0}2=-\frac 12)$
And $MD=\frac {BQ}2=\frac{\sqrt {17}}2$
So the second equation can be:
$(n+\frac 12)^2+(m-2)^2=\frac {17}4$
so we have to solve the following system of equations:
$\begin{cases}n^2+(4-m)^2=\frac{153}{10}\\(n+\frac 12)^2+(m-2)^2=\frac {17}4\end{cases}$
which gives:
$(m, n)=(\frac 1{10}, \frac 3{10})$
and:
$(m, n)=(\frac 7{10}, -\frac {21}{10})$
which also satisfies the equation of MQ:
$n^2+(m+1)^2=\frac {17}{10}=MQ^2$

Thank you for the assistance provided
